# No query results for model [App\Models\Setting] 1

Tags: php, laravel

I have been getting this error in my application when i try to sign in as an admin onto my application. But when i sign in as normal user, it works fine. Reading other solutions, i have made sure my routes are also in order to solve this issue but nothing has changed.

What could be causing this to prevent my admin from logging into the admin page please?

PS: i can't really tell where the error is coming from now.

**Routes**

```
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
    Route::get('/', 'PagesController@show');


    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'client', 'namespace' => 'User', 'middleware' => ['auth']), function () {


        Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@create');


    });

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    /**
     * Main
     */
        Route::get('dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');

    /**
     * Users
     */
    // Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function () {
        Route::get('/data', 'UsersController@anyData')->name('users.data');
        Route::get('/taskdata/{id}', 'UsersController@taskData')->name('users.taskdata');
        Route::get('/leaddata/{id}', 'UsersController@leadData')->name('users.leaddata');
        Route::get('/clientdata/{id}', 'UsersController@clientData')->name('users.clientdata');
        Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@users')->name('users.users');
        Route::post('/upload/{id}', 'FileController@upload');

        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

     /**
     * Roles
     */
        Route::resource('roles', 'RolesController');
    /**
     * Clients
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'clients'], function () {
        Route::get('/data', 'ClientsController@anyData')->name('clients.data');
        Route::post('/create/cvrapi', 'ClientsController@cvrapiStart');
        Route::post('/upload/{id}', 'DocumentsController@upload');
        Route::patch('/updateassign/{id}', 'ClientsController@updateAssign');
    });
        Route::resource('clients', 'ClientsController');
        Route::resource('documents', 'DocumentsController');


    /**
     * Tasks
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'tasks'], function () {
        Route::get('/data', 'TasksController@anyData')->name('tasks.data');
        Route::patch('/updatestatus/{id}', 'TasksController@updateStatus');
        Route::patch('/updateassign/{id}', 'TasksController@updateAssign');
        Route::post('/updatetime/{id}', 'TasksController@updateTime');
    });
        Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');

    /**
     * Leads
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'leads'], function () {
        Route::get('/data', 'LeadsController@anyData')->name('leads.data');
        Route::patch('/updateassign/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateAssign');
        Route::patch('/updatestatus/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateStatus');
        Route::patch('/updatefollowup/{id}', 'LeadsController@updateFollowup')->name('leads.followup');
    });
        Route::resource('leads', 'LeadsController');
        Route::post('/comments/{type}/{id}', 'CommentController@store');
    /**
     * Settings
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'SettingsController@index')->name('settings.index');
        Route::patch('/permissionsUpdate', 'SettingsController@permissionsUpdate');
        Route::patch('/overall', 'SettingsController@updateOverall');
    });

    /**
     * Departments
     */
        Route::resource('departments', 'DepartmentsController'); 

    /**
     * Integrations
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'integrations'], function () {
        Route::get('Integration/slack', 'IntegrationsController@slack');
    });
        Route::resource('integrations', 'IntegrationsController');

    /**
     * Notifications
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'notifications'], function () {
        Route::post('/markread', 'NotificationsController@markRead')->name('notification.read');
        Route::get('/markall', 'NotificationsController@markAll');
        Route::get('/{id}', 'NotificationsController@markRead');
    });

    /**
     * Invoices
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'invoices'], function () {
        Route::post('/updatepayment/{id}', 'InvoicesController@updatePayment')->name('invoice.payment.date');
        Route::post('/reopenpayment/{id}', 'InvoicesController@reopenPayment')->name('invoice.payment.reopen');
        Route::post('/sentinvoice/{id}', 'InvoicesController@updateSentStatus')->name('invoice.sent');
        Route::post('/newitem/{id}', 'InvoicesController@newItem')->name('invoice.new.item');
    });
        Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoicesController');
});
```

Error is

> ModelNotFoundException No query results for model [App\Models\Setting]
>   1 in Builder.php (line 312) and Handler.php (line 69)

Comment: what is the error message? and which class causes the error?

Comment: @ab_in ModelNotFoundException
No query results for model [App\Models\Setting] 1

in Builder.php (line 312) and Handler.php (line 69)

Comment: does the admin and user has seperate tables and models?

Comment: No they don't. It is the same model @ab_in

Comment: which url causes the problem?

Comment: @ab_in, i can't tell which url is causing the problem. Like in the question, `i don't know where the error is coming from now`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your route as follow

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'PagesController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Please note that `['middleware' => ['auth:admin']`.
Here admin is the gaurd name.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to your `Setting` model. you are accessing record of setting model which is not available.

ex. `Setting::findOrFail(1);`

So if model is not found then it will throw an exception `ModelNotFoundException`